# Exclude hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I use Jquery Code to extract the hyperlinks from the  item on desktops and re-set them as a source within .

```
$("article a").each(function (idx, ele) {
    var newele = $(ele).clone();
    newele.text($(ele).prop("title"));
    $("aside div.article__source").append(newele);
});
```

Is it possible to exclude certain elements/classes from this rule? That the hyperlinks of the classes  and  are ignored.

Thank you for help.

Silvio

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `:not()` selector? Something like `article a:not(.someClass)`

Comment: yes, create a selector that selects certain classes or use filter or add a check before you clone it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:not` with the class you wish to ignore:

```
$("article a:not(.ignore)").each(...);
```